# AWS ECS Api GET query with string array

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to query the AWS ECS API with a REST GET query using the following:

https://ecs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeServices&services=sample-app-service&cluster=testecscluster&Version=2014-11-13

The response is:

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2014-11-13/">
    <Error>
        <Type>Sender</Type>
        <Code>MalformedInput</Code>
        <Message>Unexpected list element termination</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>e0a57636-c8c6-11e8-a099-0b02f829db78</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Services is supposed to be an array of strings, but i can't seem to get the URL formatting correct in the URL encoding to work correct.

I've tried a few different methods and can't get the query URL to work. Anyone else have luck passing array in the url request?

I'm testing this in postman here are the headers and params:
[image: Postman]

Comment: Post the actual HTTP request, headers and body. The body is a json object, nothing special.

Comment: I added a screenshot, using AWS SIgnature authentication in Postman - so most of this is auto-populated.